# Aborting PrimeNG FileUpload's upload request

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, file-upload, primeng

Is it possible to abort upload request programmatically in [PrimeNG FileUpload](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload)? We have tried many methods using Firebugger and look at the FileUpload.js file but there is not a useful post or method anywhere except from proggress but that is also not be applicable. Any idea?

Comment: I am having this same issue. Did you find a solution? In my particular instance, I am attempting to validate the filenames of the files selected, and want to abort the upload if the files don't meet my criteria.